# 'ASCII' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 32817: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, html, css

I'm trying to get the course data from my school website and parse it to a .json file. I am stuck on the input code:

```
import urllib.request

with urllib.request.urlopen('https://catalogue.ualberta.ca/') as response:
html = response.read()

decoded = html.decode('ascii')
```

When I run this, it gives me

```
'ASCII' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 32817: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Clearly, you stop trying to decode the response as ASCII, and figure out what encoding it really is.

Comment: That page states its utf8 so data.decode("utf8")

Comment: Ok, ya sry im so new at programming. changing ascii to utf-8 worked haha.. Thank you for the answers though haha

Comment: The question remains why you're decoding at all.

Comment: cuz if I do print(html) it looks ugly but when I do print(html.decoded()) then it looks nice

Comment: print? You said your goal is a .json file...

Comment: Ya.. as I said, I have no idea how it's properly supposed to be done.. so Im just trying all these different things.. right now I'm reading the documentation for html.parser

Comment: Do you know any good libraries that parse into json format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to do you much good without the input that causes the problem, but the effect is clear.  ASCII is a 7-bit code, ordinal range 0-127.  The maximum value is 0x7f; you're beyond that.  I suspect that what you need is Unicode, not ASCII.  See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html).

```
decoded = html.decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: Okay ... Unicode, or UTF-8, is the accurate term.  Sorry; local (?) dialect.

Comment: Ya sryy im new at this

Comment: We were all new at this, once upon a time.  When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.